# Ambari shows zeppelin server not started but the server is actually up and running

Tags: ambari, apache-zeppelin

I am using HDP 2.4.2 and I had previously installed the zeppelin server. It was working fine but today when i restarted the cluster ( AWS nodes were restarted), Ambari shows that Zeppelin server is not running and fails to start the server with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.4/services/ZEPPELIN/package/scripts/master.py", line 235, in <module>
    Master().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 219, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.4/services/ZEPPELIN/package/scripts/master.py", line 169, in start
    + params.zeppelin_log_file, user=params.zeppelin_user)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 158, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 121, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 238, in action_run
    tries=self.resource.tries, try_sleep=self.resource.try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start >> /var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-setup.log' returned 1. /usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh: line 187: /var/run/zeppelin-notebook/zeppelin-zeppelin-ip-10-0-0-11.eu-west-1.compute.internal.pid: Permission denied
cat: /var/run/zeppelin-notebook/zeppelin-zeppelin-ip-10-0-0-11.eu-west-1.compute.internal.pid: No such file or directory
```

In the zeppelin logs:

ERROR [2016-06-06 03:20:36,714] ({main} VFSNotebookRepo.java[list]:140) - Can't read note file:///usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib/notebook/screenshots java.io.IOException: file:///usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib/notebook/screenshots/note.json not found

ERROR [2016-06-06 03:34:12,795] ({main} Notebook.java[loadNoteFromRepo]:330) - Failed to load 2BHU1G67J java.io.IOException: file:///usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib/notebook/2BHU1G67J is not a directory

But for some reason, the zeppelin port is listening and despite these errors, the zeppelin server is running fine and executing all the queries. Please advice on how to correct the issue in Ambari and start the service without error from ambari.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the PID file for the zeppelin service. It's either owned by the wrong user or has the wrong permissions. Manually stop the zeppelin service then delete the pid file locate at: `/var/run/zeppelin-notebook/zeppelin-zeppelin-ip-10-0-0-11.eu-west-1.compute.internal.pid`. Double check the owner/permissions on the `/var/run/zeppelin-notebook` folder as well. You should then be able to restart the service in the Ambari UI.

Comment: Thanks cjackson! I had figured that much.. But I found out that the issue was because the default location used by zeppelin to find the pid file was /var/run/zeppelin and not /var/run/zeppelin-notebook.

Once i changed that, the service started from Ambari. I reported the same bug to the developers as well.